# Upgrade to PHP 5.6 PDO drivers Not found (Symfony2)

Tags: pdo, apache2.4, php-5.6, apache-modules

Just upgraded to PHP v5.6.22 from PHP v5.5.9 and my Symfony2 project is complaining about few things. I assume many of my modules are not enabled like PDO and curl. 1rst thing I am getting this when I go to my dev site:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in "Many Many directories of Doctrine.."
```

In my **phpinfo** my PDO drivers are empty and say `enabled ... no value`

Running command:

```
composer update
```

I get errors about my `curl` not enabled. Seems like all my mods of php are not enabled since I upgraded PHP.

To upgrade I did the following:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo apt-get upgrade

#Tell Apache2 what version of php to use
sudo a2dismod php5
sudo service apache2 restart (now apache is not using any php!)
sudo a2enmod php5.6
sudo service apache2 restart (now apache is using php5.6 !)
```

What's next?

Comment: I've done exactly the same as you. Found your question via google. php -i|grep PDO shows pdo enabled but is not there in phpinfo.

Comment: Same thing here. Did you guys ever find a way round this?